# How to know some equation can be solved or not arithmetically?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, abstract-algebra, recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations

**Problem**

I was given the following equation to solve for x

$$
A = 2(x-1)^{-N} - B x^{-N} \sqrt{(x^{2N}-1)/(x^2 - 1)}
$$

A, B, N is constant, N is positive integer, and $x>2$,

I want to solve the equation for x

But don't get hung up on it.

**My solution**

...was simply to use a calculator, which gave me a seemingly irrational number, which is understandable given the presence of pi.

But at the same time, I was wondering if this equation was solvable by typical algebraic methods, like substitutions yielding a quadratic equation for example.

But more generally, I started wondering how I could determine whether or not it is solvable algebraically.

**Question**

Do we have any "if such-and-such is not satisfied, go numerical" rules of thumb? Or do we just make a judgment call?

Comment: What presence of pi?

Comment: Except for deliberately made-up examples, complicated equations usually are not solvable in "closed form".  If you don't see an obvious way to solve it algebraically, do it numerically.

Comment: @RobertIsrael missspell sorry. we don`t need PI

Comment: @RobertIsrael I just want to know that the above equaton can be solved in closed form or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$, if the goal is to solve the equation:

$$
a = \frac{2}{(x-1)^n} - \frac{b}{x^n}\sqrt{\frac{x^{2n}-1}{x^2-1}} \tag{1}
$$

- if $b = 0$, $(1)$ reduces to an elementary polynomial equation:

$$
(x-1)^n = \frac{2}{a} 
\quad \quad \Rightarrow \quad \quad
x = 1 + \sqrt[n]{\frac{2}{a}}
$$

- if $b \ne 0$, $(1)$ can still be reduced to a polynomial equation:

$$
\frac{\left(x^{2n}-1\right)\left(x-1\right)^{2n}}{x^2-1} = \frac{x^{2n}\left(2-a(x-1)^n\right)^2}{b^2} \tag{2}
$$

but, unlike the previous case, we cannot avoid fixing the value of $n$. Furthermore, due to the squaring, spurious solutions may arise, so the solutions of $(2)$ necessarily will be verified by replacing them in $(1)$.

---

As a first example, let us consider the case $a=1$, $b=1$, $n=1$ which leads to:

$$
\left(x^2 - 2x - 1\right)\left(x^2 - 4x + 1\right) = 0
$$

which is verified for $x = 1 \pm \sqrt{2}$ or $x = 2 \pm \sqrt{3}$, but only $x = 1 \pm \sqrt{2}$ also satisfy $(1)$.

---

As a second example, let us consider the case $a=1$, $b=1$, $n=2$ which leads to:

$$
\underbrace{x^8 - 4x^7 + x^6 + 8x^5 - 6x^4 + 8x^3 - 7x^2 + 4x - 1}_{p(x)} = 0
$$

which being a non-special polynomial of degree greater than four doesn't allow to express the roots through radicals. So, once the *eight first-attempt roots* on the unit circle have been calculated:

$$
x_k = \cos(2\,k\,\pi/8) + \text{i}\,\sin(2\,k\,\pi/8)
\quad \quad \text{with} \; k = 1,2,\dots,8
$$

it's sufficient to update them about ten times by applying the *Aberth-Ehrlich method*:

$$
x_k' = x_k - \left(\frac{p'(x_k)}{p(x_k)} - \sum_{j=1;\,j\ne k}^8 \frac{1}{x_k-x_j}\right)^{-1}
$$

from which:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& x_1 = 0.356214 + 0.443627\,\text{i}\,; \\
& x_2 = 0.356214 - 0.443627\,\text{i}\,; \\
& x_3 = -0.231134 + 0.805661\,\text{i}\,; \\
& x_4 = -1.64147 - 1.19851\cdot 10^{-94}\,\text{i}\,; \\
& x_5 = 2.79585 + 2.96462\cdot 10^{-20}\,\text{i}\,; \\
& x_6 = -0.231134 - 0.805661\,\text{i}\,; \\
& x_7 = 0.445743 - 2.06795\cdot 10^{-25}\,\text{i}\,; \\
& x_8 = 2.14971 + 3.06534\cdot 10^{-46}\,\text{i}\,; \\
\end{aligned}
$$

among which only $x_3,x_6,x_7,x_8$ also satisfy $(1)$.

---

On the other hand, if $a,b,n$ can only assume values such that $(1)$ is always verified for a real value close to $x = \overline{x}$, which is the only solution of interest, then all this work can be avoided by defining:

$$
f(x) := a - \frac{2}{(x-1)^n} + \frac{b}{x^n}\sqrt{\frac{x^{2n}-1}{x^2-1}}
$$

and applying the *Newton-Raphson method*:

$$
x_0 = \overline{x},
\quad \quad
x_i = x_{i-1} - \frac{f(x_{i-1})}{f'(x_{i-1})}
\quad \quad \text{with} \; i=1,2,\dots
$$

I hope I have given an idea of the reasoning that is usually done in these circumstances.

Comment: what if we know the n is positive integer greater than 1 but not determined? does it cannot be solved in closed foam?

Comment: ok then you mean trying to solve this analytically is the most stupid thing thanks

Answer (score 1):

By rearranging and squaring we obtain
$$
\frac{(2(x-1)^{-N}-A)^2}{B^2x^{-2N}}=\frac{x^{2N}-1}{x^2-1}=x^{2N-2}+x^{2N-4}+\cdots +x^2+1.
$$
This gives a polynomial equation in $x$, which one can solve.

Comment: but what if we don`t know exact value of N? if N is positive integer but unkwon then we cannot solve your equation

Comment: On the contrary, we can solve it for any $N$. It always has complex solutions for any $N$. Of course, the solutions will depend on $N$.

Comment: I can change N manuallly so solving for N doesn`t have any meaning sorry

Comment: It has a meaning. For example, $x^N=1$ has the $N$-th roots of unity as solutions, for every $N$.

Comment: $x^N$ cannot be 1 because I have said $x>2$ and N is positive integer

Comment: Then consider $x^N=9$ as an example. Do you only allow real $x$? If so, why?

Comment: For practical use imaginary part is not considered